# How to monitor cwnd and ssthresh values for a TCP connection?

Tags: linux, tcp

I wish to ascertain these values when a packet is sent or received over a socket connection. Is there any existing tool which does this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree with the answer given by Nemo. Wireshark (as well as dumpcap, tcpdump) are not capable of measuring/logging the cwnd and the ssthresh, as those are not field in the tcp datagrams but are only values that reside inside the kernel as kernel structures. Congestion control data is not transmitted over the wire, only flow control data is.

To monitor those values, either implement [`get_info`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=tcp_get_info) and sample the data periodically, or take a look at the `tcp_probe` kernel module (see: http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcptesting)

UPDATE: I've created a patched version of the tcp_probe module that can be used for monitoring the cwnd and ssthread, see https://github.com/Dynalon/tcp_probe_fixed

Answer (score 10):

The [ss](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) utility will generate this output for sockets:

```
# ss -i
State      Recv-Q Send-Q      Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port   
ESTAB      0      2054000          1.2.3.4:34069          1.2.3.5:ssh     
     htcp wscale:11,11 rto:247 rtt:47/0.75 ato:40 cwnd:1542 ssthresh:742 send 380.1Mbps rcv_rtt:14 rcv_space:64240
```

You can check the cwnd/ssthresh values from it.

Comment: Is there any documentation on what each of these columns mean? E.g., 'send' is 347.6Kbps, what does it mean?

Comment: What about macOS then? I tried `lsof -Tfqs -iTCP -sTCP:ESTABLISHED`, but can not find the cwnd/ssthresh value in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "monitor", [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) might do the trick.

See also the [/proc/net/tcp documentation](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/networking/proc_net_tcp.txt).  (No, I do not really follow it; you might need to dig into the kernel sources to make sense of it...)

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can I get these values from Wireshark?

Comment: Wireshark has a GUI.  You tell it what packets you are interested in (by port number, IP address, network interface, whatever), click "Start", move some traffic over your TCP connection, click "Stop", and then Wireshark will dissect the protocol.  It will figure out which packets are part of which TCP connection, and with each ACK it will include the cwnd.  (But not the ssthresh...  I do not know how to monitor that one, since it is internal to the network stack)

Comment: To find the ssthresh just look at a graph for the position where slow-start stops and congestion avoidance(AI) starts. The junction between the two phases is the ssthresh. There is no automated way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool that can monitor these values. http://www.umic-mesh.net/downloads/flowgrind.html