# Get cwnd of my TCP connection from a program

Tags: c++, linux, networking, tcp, congestion-control

I am creating a TCP connection from my linux program with boost.asio. I wonder how do I get the value of its congestion window (cwnd) from the program? The only way I know of is to parse [`/proc/net/tcp`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/proc_net_tcp.txt), but this does not feel right. I'd rather use a dedicated syscall to get this info.

A solution to a similar question ([How to monitor cwnd and ssthresh values for a TCP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6632715/261217)) suggests using TCP Probe, but it feels even less appealing.

So what is the best way to get the value of cwnd?

Comment: The congestion window is per side, and it is not communicated to the other side. It also changes constantly, growing until there is a problem, then shrinking before growing again. You could never get the sender's congestion window from the receiver.

Comment: I inderstand that and I only want to know _my_ congestion window _now_.

Comment: i think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960012/linux-how-to-get-tcp-socket-options-given-socket-descriptor) also answers yours

Comment: also here is [struct tcp_info](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h#L214). `tcpi_snd_cwnd` (line 246) should be congestion window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out `getsockopt()` is able to return the same `tcp_info` when called with `TCP_INFO` option:

```
  tcp_info tcpi = {};
  socklen_t len = sizeof(tcp_info);
  getsockopt(tcp_socket, SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, &tcpi, &len);
  tcpi.tcpi_snd_cwnd;  // <-- CWND
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with [netlink](https://linux.die.net/man/7/netlink) and INET_DIAG-sockets based on this helpful example: https://github.com/kristrev/inet-diag-example